# Transfer WebMail Client mails to another WebMail Cleint

Tags: email, pop3, webmail, roundcube

I was using web mail client provided from my hosting company. Everything i was reading or sending it was done there.

Now i want to install my own web mail client like Round cube or similar.

1) Can i transfer my mails from old one to my new?
2) When ill connect my mail to my own round cube, does that work as Outlook (download all inbox mails via POP3)?

Any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what other methods you can access your mail from your hosting company.

If you can access your mail via POP3 then use a tool like fetchmail to transfer your messages: http://fetchmail.berlios.de/

If they use another webmail service like Yahoo then you can use something like fetchyahoo http://fetchyahoo.twizzler.org/  - this page also lists alternatives for other webmail systems.